# Stop backbone from adding surrounding divs to a view?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am using Handlebars.js as a templating tool for my Backbone.js app. My render functions in my views usually look like the following:

```
  var source = $("#round").html();
  var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
  var context = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.model));
  var html = template(context);
  $(this.el).html(html);
  return this;
```

The above is appended to the main app view through the following code(this is the code that calls the above code):

```
$('div#round-container', this.el).append(roundView.render().el);
```

My Handlebars template handles all of the styling and layout, so I leave the "el" element of a view blank. Backbone.js automatically adds surrounding div tags around the Handlebars template. I assume this is because the "el" element is blank. Is there a way to prevent the addition of the surrounding div tags? Thanks!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

What's happening is `this.el` is created on the fly because it was never explicitly set by you.  You have two options:

1. You should specify the element you want to create with `tagName`, `className` and/or `id` and let backbone create that for you.
2. In `render` you should set `this.el` to the contents of your handlebars template.  So you would have `this.el = $(template(context))`.

The docs have an expanded explanation - http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-el

Comment: setElement is a nice option too

Comment: After going with option 2., submit event is not fired

Comment: @svlada, `setElement` also calls `this.undelegateEvents();` and `this.delegateEvents();` which ensures the events in the events hash are applied to the new element. You can call them yourselft if setElement is out of the question. [source](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-162)

Answer (score 5):

Another easy way is to append the childnodes of the rendered element instead

```
$('div#round-container', this.el).append(roundView.render().el.childNodes);
```

Comment: Dont use this, you will lose all your event in your views.

Answer (score 3):

Or append the html of the rendered element, e.g.:

```
$('div#round-container', this.el).append(roundView.render().el.html());
```