# Backbone Marionette View And Wrapping Container

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

Is there a way that I can tell backbone/marionette not to automatically add a the wrapping container tag when rendering a view to a region?

For example, lets say I want to display a list of items.  The way I want to do that is by having one composite view looking looks this:

```
<ul>
</ul>
```

And then a item view that looks like this:

```
<li><%= title %></li>
```

Now I can easily get the same output by changing what the tag used for the auto generated element is however the biggest reason I would not have the tag automatically generated by backbone/marionette is because I want to keep as much html in the template as possible.  If for whatever reason I want to change the list to a table, if all the HTML is contained in templates, I only have to change the two template files.  The other way would require me to change 2 template files and 2 javascript files (less file I have to change to make a change, the less chance for error).  I just like to have that level of separation of concern.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extra divs in itemviews and layouts in Backbone.Marionette](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183130/extra-divs-in-itemviews-and-layouts-in-backbone-marionette)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither Backbone nor Marionette have built in support for this. But I imagine if you could get this behaviour with a few tweaks.

`Backbone.View` has a method called `_ensureElement` that constructs the `el` from `tagName` and `className` if the `el` is not provided.

You could override `_ensureElement` to render the template first an then use it's first tag name as the `tagName` for the view. You'd also need to override `Marionette.Renderer.render` to strip the template's outer tag.

There maybe a better choice of methods to override to achieve this logic. I would also advise that you provide a flag somewhere to turn this behaviour on selectively so you could mix and match as needed, which would also help in debugging.